# Is there an equivalent to <%@ Reference Control="~/MyControl.ascx"> to use in the code behind?

Tags: asp.net, reference, code-behind, user-controls

I would like to dynamically add a user control to my page.

I have read you need to add the following line to the page before you can use LoadControl in the code behind.

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/MyControl.ascx">
```

However the page I'm working on is just a custom class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`, which all my master pages inherit from. This I have no where to put the reference control line.

Is there a way to reference the control in the `.vb` file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this -

```
Dim myControl As Control = CType(Page.LoadControl("yourcontrol.ascx"), Control)
Panel1.Controls.Add(myControl)
```

You'd need to add a Panel or PlaceHolder control to your page to hold your control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do have the following on my page:

Dim lContentTable As User_Controls.Content_Table = LoadControl("../User_Controls/Content_Table.ascx")

However when I try to access the page in the browser after building the project without errors, I get the following message:

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'User_Controls.Content_Table' is not defined.

I assumed this was because I had not added a reference to the control on the aspx page as described above.

Comment: did you remember to include the project declaration at the top? Sorry I work c# but it would be something like 'using Myproj.User_Controls.Content_Table;'

Comment: @Smartie, you could try rocky's suggestion, or declare your variable as a `Control` object as in the example. Hopefully, one of those will work for you.

Comment: Neither is working, I think there must be some other problem preventing it from working :S